# Plotting secants to a curve with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a sequence of secants to a curve using frame overlays and ppgfplots. What I'm trying is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc,intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center, 
      axis y line=middle, 
      xlabel=$t$,
      ylabel=$S$,
      ytick={0,50,...,650},
      xtick={0,1,...,10},
      restrict y to domain=0:600,           
      domain=0:11
    ]
    \addplot[blue,thick] {x+5*x^2};
    \addplot[color=blue,only marks,mark=*] coordinates{(8,328)};    
    \foreach \ta in {4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7} {
      \foreach \Sa in {\ta+5.0*\ta^2}
        \only<+-+>{
          \addplot[color=blue,only marks,mark=*] coordinates{(\ta,\Sa)};
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{(328.0-\Sa)/(8.0-\ta)};
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{328-\m*8.0};
          \addplot[black,thick] {\m*x+\b};
          \addplot[red,thick] {\m};
        };  
    }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}         

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that point (8,328) be kept fixed and the secants approach it from the left.

I'm not sure what is happening but it seems that the angular coefficient of my secants is being wrongly calculated, as I can see by plotting it. The sequence of coefficients `m` should be `[61.0,63.5,66.0,68.5,71.0,73.5,76.0,78.5]` but this is not what I'm getting.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Sa}{\ta+5.0*\ta^2}`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=center, 
      axis y line=middle, 
      xlabel=$t$,
      ylabel=$S$,
      ytick={0,50,...,650},
      xtick={0,1,...,10},
      restrict y to domain=0:600,
      domain=0:11
    ]
    \addplot[blue,thick] {x+5*x^2};
    \addplot[color=blue,only marks,mark=*] coordinates{(8,328)};
    \foreach \ta in {4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sa}{\ta+5.0*\ta^2}% <- changed
        \only<+-+>{
          \addplot[color=blue,only marks,mark=*] coordinates{(\ta,\Sa)};
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{(328.0-\Sa)/(8.0-\ta)};
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{328-\m*8.0};
          \addplot[black,thick] {\m*x+\b};
          \addplot[red,thick] {\m};
        };
    }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, kind Sir! This was driving me crazy. I had already created all the plots manually, just in case. Thank you.

Comment: Or Madam. Forgive my involuntary sexism.